# Installation of plyr in R on Ubuntu does not work

Tags: plyr

I am having difficulties with installing plyr in R (on Ubuntu). The very same problem has been posted in various forums before (in fact I just posted this myself a while ago), but none of the suggested solutions there worked for me.

To summarize, I am trying to install it using this command (output below):

```
install.packages("plyr")
```

Installing package into ‘`/home/m2108/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0`’
(as ‘`lib`’ is unspecified)

Warning message:

> package ‘plyr’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

Then I have tried to manually download the package from the cran server and use this command instead and receive the same error:

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source") Installing package into ‘/home/m2108/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) ERROR: this R is version 3.0.2, package 'plyr' requires R >= 3.1.0 Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘/home/m2108/Downloads/plyr_1.8.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have also ensured that I have internet access from within R. I have also tried to run the installation from  within RStudio and from the console.

Does anyone have an idea, what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried to install it from GitHub using this command:
sudo su - -c "R -e \"devtools::install_github('hadley/plyr')\""
And received the following error  message:
ERROR: this R is version 3.0.2, package 'plyr' requires R >= 3.1.0
Error: Command failed (1)
Execution halted
I am assuming that this error message (unlike the previous default message about R version 3.0.2) is accurate and I will try to update my version of R now.

Comment: After the Update, it worked!!